# No such table with qsqlite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

I'm trying to connect to a database in my home directory `C:\Users\mahmoud\trade.db`

My code looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::initializeDatabase()
{
    QFileInfo db_path(QDir::homePath() + "/trade.db");
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", db_path.absoluteFilePath());
    if(!db.open() || !db_path.exists()) {
        this->showMessage("Database not open or does not exist.");
        qApp->exit(1);
    }
}
```

I'm using Qt 5 and I've made sure that the QSQLite driver is loaded by running

```
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

The table I'm querying does exist in the database I'm connecting to, I've checked using the local SQLite client.

**edit:** the schema for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `merchants` (
        `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `merchant_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
        `phone` TEXT,
        `address` TEXT,
        `notes` TEXT
);
```

I'm running this query `select * from merchants;` using a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton`

The code for the button click slot is the following:

```
void MainWindow::showMessage(QString str)
{
    QMessageBox mb;
    mb.setText(str);
    mb.exec();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    if (open){
        QSqlQuery query(db);
        bool done = query.exec(ui->lineEdit->text());
        if(done) {
            this->showMessage("OK!");
        } else {
            QErrorMessage qerr(this);
            qerr.showMessage(query.lastError().text());
            qerr.exec();
        }
    } else {
        this->showMessage("Database not open.");
    }

}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

[image: error]

Comment: So you are not getting the error message "Database not open or does not exist."?? I am not sure how we can help in that case given the code you posted. I mean I use sqlite databases under Qt and my tables are all found. I suggest you post your query code. Perhaps the error is there.

Comment: @drescherjm updated question.

Comment: I don't use `\`` as a quote in my sqlite table creation however I don't think this is a problem as SQLITE supports several quoting methods. I don't see why you have this issue.

Comment: You may want to check !db_path.exists() before `db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", db_path.absoluteFilePath());` because if the database did not exist at the path you will get a new empty database.

Comment: Looking at my code I see that I use `db.setDatabaseName(sqliteDbFullPath);`  after `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()`

Comment: @drescherjm the quoting is the sqlite `.schema` command output, I don't use it either.